# Caracteres extraños o página dañada en aspx

Tags: c#

Si borro cierta línea o la modifico aspx me devuelve un error al intentar cargar la página:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAvisoImport" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content" styles="min-width: 1000px !important;max-width: 1000px !important;max-height: 600px !important;">
            <!--header-->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <input type='button' id='btnpopupImport' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true' value='x' style="display: none" />
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <br />
                <i class="fa fa-bell fa-3x"></i>
                <h4 id="lblAvisoImport" class="semi-bold"><span id="spanAvisoImport"></span></h4>
            </div>
```

Específicamente la línea que genera el problema es la siguiente:

```
<div class="modal-content" style="min-width: 1000px !important;max-width: 1000px !important;max-height: 600px !important;">
```

Al querer quitar el contenido del tag `style` se genera el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me hace suponer que es un problema de codificación de caracteres de la página, o cual es realmente el problema, porque aunque modifique completamente un fragmento de HTML de dicha página el error aparece.

Es un problema que me tenía renegando desde hace tiempo y no encuentro la forma o el editor que me muestre cual es el caracter extraño.

Comment: ¿Por qué dice **styles** y no **style**? `<div class="modal-content" styles="min-width: 1000px !important;max-width: 1000px !important;max-height: 600px !important;">` ¿Ya corregiste eso? Además aquí, pon punto y coma: `style="display: none"` al final y sé **estricto con tu código** no uses en unas partes comillas simples y en otras comillas dobles. **Debes revisar tu código letra por letra** y darle uniformidad.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ese no es mi codigo alguien mas lo escribió hace ya bastante solo tengo que mantenerlo funcionando porque es un muerto andante, eso termina siendo una trivialidad comparado al resto de las malas practicas que tiene, volviendo a la pregunta le coloque ```styles``` (agregando la **s**) a proposito para desactivar ese estilo porque defasaba la modal es una solución atada con alambre pero esa linea tenia que modificar, porque si intento borrar o modificar el contenido entre esas comillas dobles o modifico el contenido salta el error de la captura que puedes observar arriba.

Comment: Bueno, pero el colocar _styles_ no creo que te resuelva el problema, más bien te podría crear otro. Si en realidad el problema viene de ahí, ¿por qué no colocar el `<div>` sin la etiqueta `style`? Imagino que también habrás revisado el CSS, en especial lo que respecta a la clase `modal-content`... además esa mezcla de CSS con nombres de clase y estilos directos usando `style...`, el uso a mansalva de `important!...`, etc, etc hace de ese código heredado algo lamentable que sería mejor quizá **¿reescribir?**

Comment: Si totalmente es un desastre, ni hablar lo ilegible que es pero no tengo asignada a la misma un tiempo razonable para reescribirla (metieron todo un solo archivo tiene mas de 3000 lineas, sin contar la master page que es otro desastre igual de grande) y nunca se siguió un patrón de buenas practicas ni siquiera sentido común, es un horror ver el proyecto completo, pero al menos directamente se esta migrando completamente la app a una nueva versión desde 0.